# How to open a file which is stored in HDFS in pySpark using with open

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to open a file which is stored in HDFS - Here the input file is from HDFS - If I give the file as bellow , I wont be able to open , It will show as file not found

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
conf = SparkConf ()
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
def getMovieName():
    movieNames = {}
    with open ("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split("|")
            mID = fields[0]
            mName = fields[1]
            movieNames[int(fields[0])] = fields[1]
            return movieNames
nameDict = sc.broadcast(getMovieName())
```

My assumption was to use like

```
with open (sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat")) as f:
```

But that also didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the `textfile` into `rdd`:

```
rdd_name = sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/movieStat")
```

You can use `collect()` in order to use it in pure python (not recommended - use only on very small data), or use spark `rdd` methods in order to manipulate it using `pyspark` methods (the recommended way)

More info [pyspark API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.html):

> **textFile(name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True)**
>
> Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all
>   nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an
>   RDD of Strings.
>
> If use_unicode is False, the strings will be kept as str (encoding as
>   utf-8), which is faster and smaller than unicode. (Added in Spark 1.2)
>
> ```
> >>> path = os.path.join(tempdir, "sample-text.txt")
> >>> with open(path, "w") as testFile:
> ...    _ = testFile.write("Hello world!")
> >>> textFile = sc.textFile(path)
> >>> textFile.collect()
> [u'Hello world!']
> ```