# Read a model (.pkl and .scl) file stored in HDFS

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, pickle, webhdfs

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522154/how-to-open-a-file-which-is-stored-in-hdfs-in-pyspark-using-with-open), but has difference.

I have two models model_1.scl and model_2.pkl saved in the HDFS.

```
pickle.load(open('model_1.scl', 'rb'))
pickle.load(open('model_2.pkl', 'rb'))
```

For textfile, I can simply use:

```
sc.textFile('hdfs://abc_cluster/user/user_1/textfile.txt').collect()
```

But how about non-text file, such as my model file? It will makes non-textfile fail for pickle.load( )?

Any method to read model file stored on HDFS?

Comment: is that model file consisting binary data ?

Comment: use `sc.binaryFiles`